# Python REPL Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a homework task where I need to write a Python adder REPL. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Below is the challenge:

The Adder language has only a few simple statements:

- `quit` - Exit the REPL or terminate a program.
- `input var` - Prompt for and allow the user to enter a value for the variable named var.
- `print val` - Print the value `val`.
- `var gets val` - variable `var` is assigned the value `val`.
- `var adds val` - variable `var` has the value `val` added to it.

Where:

- `var` is always a variable name that contains only letters; and
- `val` can be either:
- a variable name that contains only letters;

An example would be:

```
Welcome to the Adder REPL.
??? a gets 1
??? input b
Enter a value for b: 2
??? c gets a
??? c adds b
??? print a
a equals 1
??? print b
b equals 2
??? print c
c equals 3
??? print z
z is undefined.
??? print 32
32
??? blerg
Syntax error.
??? 23 gets z
Syntax error.
??? quit
Goodbye.
```

My code is as follows:

```
REPL_control = True

def input_loop():
    print("Welcome to the Adder REPL")
    while REPL_control == True:
        user_input = input(str("??? "))

        if user_input == 'a gets 1':
            a_value = 1

        if user_input == 'input b':
            b_input = input("Enter a value for b: ")
            b_value = b_input

        if user_input == 'c gets a':
            c_value = a_value 

        if user_input == 'c adds b':
            c_value = c_value + int(b_value)

        if user_input == 'print a':
            print('a equals ', a_value)

        if user_input == 'print b':
            print('b equals', b_value)
    
        if user_input == 'print c':
            print('c equals', c_value)

        if user_input == 'print z':
            print('z is undefined.')
        
        if user_input == 'print 32':
            print('32')

        if user_input == 'blerg':
            print('Syntax error.')
    
        if user_input == '23 gets z':
            print("Syntax error.")

        #quit program is 'quit' is supplied
        if user_input == 'quit':
            print("Goodbye.")
            break


input_loop()
```

This can be thought of as essentially pseudocode. My if statements produce the correct outputs, and my quit function works. However, I need a way to store and access the commands. I was thinking a dictionary with keys pointing to the relevant  commands. Example:

```
adder_commands = {
    "quit_command": "quit", 
    "input_command": "input {}",
    "print_command": "print {}"
}
```

However, I'm unsure how I can reference these from the user input.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you name the key like actual command you will use, not like *quit_command*? That way you can just check if user input gets any hit in dictionary.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to have a formatting error where the code that is supposed to be inside the function is not properly indented. To fix indent everything you want inside the function one more level.

Something you could do to solve this problem is perhaps create a menu like interface where a User offers a number that represents an index in a list of a command. That or the dictionary idea is good as well you would just probably want some easier codes for them to input such as q for quit etc.

The important thing to remember is that input() function in python will take anything the user enters and convert it to a string so you will have numbers in a string format meaning 32 != "32" in python.

Happy coding!